# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

I am getting the error on OnSelectedIndexChanging

My aspx file

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" ID="product_all_detail_list" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanging="product_detail_list_SelectedIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="product_all_detail_list_SelectedIndexChanged" >
       <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lb_id" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Label>
                 </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                           
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The code behind

```
 protected void product_detail_list_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
 //   GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);

    all_details.Visible = true;
    Label id = (Label)row.FindControl("lb_id");
    dal.Fillgrid(product_all_detail_list, q);
}
```

Is the code is correct?
I also tried for  `GridViewRow row = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;`

but getting an error like `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: `SelectedIndexChanging` is an event on `GridView`, so casting `sender as Button` yields `null`

Answer (score 0):

your btn is not inside the GridView when you call btn.NamingContainer it will give ContentPlaceHolder object.

you will get an exception when you cast ContentPlaceHolder to GridViewRow

try with SelectedIndex like below to get the selected row.

```
GridViewRow row = product_all_detail_list.Rows[product_all_detail_list.SelectedIndex];
```

for More information take a look at this [url](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/772241/Error-occured-Unable-to-cast-object-of-type-System)